# How to bring the attribute value of the simple product associated with bundle or configurable product on product detail page

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community

We are building a website having bundles product. I want to display the attributes of the simple product associated with bundle product on bundle product detail page. I guess it is possible as if name and price can be retrieved attributes too can be.

I was searching through `bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option` but didn't find any solution. I tried using `getAttributeName`, `getAttributeText` etc they didn't work.

I know the answer is somewhere around there. Can anyone guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: I recall a `getUsedProductIds()` method (or similar name) but I'll have to look for it.

Comment: can you please look and tell me. It would really be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of bundled product and then do whatever you want with them (e.g. load model, get attributes etc.):

```
$product->getTypeInstance(true)->getChildrenIds($product->getId(), false);
```

Comment: I tried to add this code in options.phtml, bundle.phtml, radio.phtml and view.phtml but it doesn't work. Can you please explain in little detail regarding where to add this code and how to retrieve the value ?

Comment: Anywhere where `$product` is a valid instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`.